# Правильно разнести функции по файлам с++ внутри программы

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Пишу программу но споткнулся об один момент, как разнести функционал по разным файлам, для удобства чтения..

Файл заголовок win_sockets.h:

```
int InitializeSockets();
```

Файл кода win_sockets.cpp:

```
int InitializeSockets() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    ADDRINFO hints;
    ADDRINFO* addrResult = NULL;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    int result;
    result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (result != 0) {
        std::cout << "WSA start fail, result = " << result << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

}
```

код main.cpp:

```
 #include "win_sockets.h"
        int main()
        {
            InitializeSockets();
            ...
result = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "22081", &hints, &addrResult);
...
```

Ошибки VS2019 что:

hints
addrResult
ConnectSocket

Не определены, как можно это исправить?

> Ошибка (активно)  E0020   идентификатор "hints" не определен  Project5
> sender.cpp    17

Comment: попробуйте вот так `ADDRINFO hints{};` - должно уйти

Comment: сделайте эти переменные **не** локальными, а глобальными. Дальше в хедер их тоже нужно добавить с приставкой `extern тип имя ;`

Comment: Приводите настоящее сообщение об ошибке и [mcve]. А то так можно разве что гадать по хрустальному шару, что происходит бесполезная инициализация локальной переменной `addrResult` в `InitializeSockets`, а не той, что в `main`.

Comment: @user7860670 добавил вывод и код ошибки.

Comment: ¿Если у вас ошибка *"идентификатор "hints" не определен"*, то что же вы пишите *"Ошибки компиляции что: hints addrResult ConnectSocket Не инициализированы"*? ¿Зачем вводите читающих в заблуждение? Вот как раз по этому вопросы, не содержащие mcve, и должны закрываться.

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо. не так часто задаю вопросы, но поправил и учту на будущее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I.

Внутри функции объявления переменных

```
int InitializeSockets() {
  WSADATA wsaData;
  ADDRINFO hints;
  ADDRINFO* addrResult = NULL;
  SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
```

работают только при вызове функции, а дальше после окончания работы этих переменных больше не существует. Если вы хотите, чтобы переменные хранились постоянно в *единственном* экземпляре, то можно их объявить глобальными.

```
ADDRINFO hints;
ADDRINFO* addrResult = NULL;
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

int InitializeSockets() {
  WSADATA wsaData;
```

А чтобы они были видны при компиляции другого файла, их нужно *предварительно* объявить в хедере, что они существуют с приставкой `extern`.

win_sockets.h:

```
int InitializeSockets();

extern ADDRINFO hints;
extern ADDRINFO* addrResult ;
extern  SOCKET ConnectSocket ;
```

---

II.

Если у вас экземпляр сокета не в единичном экземпляре, то желательно создать стуктуру/класс с этими переменными. И передавать указатель/ссылку на данную структуру. Это будет уже не процедурный стиль, а объектный. Тогда можно избавиться от глобальных переменных, и объявить только структуру.

win_sockets.h:

```
struct stSocket {
  ADDRINFO hints;
  ADDRINFO* addrResult = NULL;
  SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
};

int InitializeSockets(stSocket * );
```

win_sockets.cpp:

```
int InitializeSockets(stSocket * const s) {
  WSADATA wsaData;
  int result;
  result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
  if (result != 0) {
    std::cout << "WSA start fail, result = " << result << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  ZeroMemory(&s->hints, sizeof(s->hints));
  s->hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  s->hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  s->hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
  return 0 ;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "win_sockets.h"
int main()
  {
      stSocket s ;
      InitializeSockets( & s );
        ...
    result = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "22081", &s . hints, &s . addrResult);
```

Comment: Это вполне может прокатить, однако совет плодить глобальные переменные - откровенно дурной.

Comment: А что-бы вы посоветовали другое, для начала? @user7860670

Comment: Ну, я бы предложил объявить эти переменные (в данном случае) в ```main```, а в ```InitializeSockets``` передать их по ссылке.

Comment: Ну можно конечно написать класс/структуру. И передавать его по ссылке. Но это уже совсем другая история.. @user7860670